# flashing screen on windows startup

Tags: windows-11

OS build 22621.2070
When windows 11 boots into desktop, sometimes I get a flashing screen.  Restarting does nothing. I do a restore to a couple of days ago and it is fine till it happens again. Ive turned off all updates.  The restore only lists webview2 runtime as a changed program, but it works when this is updated, after the restore.

When the screen flashes, nothing actually loads but I can pull up task manager and restart etc. But I cant access desktop or windows bar.

I uninstalled the preview build (not so sure why I get these) and after the restart the screen was flashing.  Used restore and it put the update back and working.  Till something happens and then it flashes on boot.

How can I fix or diagnose the issue?

The full red is my windows 11 color.  Flashes full red, then shows empty desktop, with bg pic, full red and so on

[image]
[image]

Comment: When it's red (no icons), if you do ctrl+alt+del and bring up task manager, is explorer.exe running? And if now, if you do File > Run New Task > explorer.exe does it spring back into life?

Comment: Yes I can only seem to input on the red screen.  Explore.exe is running but does disappear and come back. There is no file but a run new task button.  Explorer.exe doesn't help. It shows multiple explorer.exe and then back to one.  I'm resetting windows now as system restore stoped working